# jQuery: copy values of all inputs (selects, radiobuttons, checkboxes etc) from one part of the page to another one

Tags: jquery, css, select, input, checkbox

There are two divs with different ids but absolutely with the same structure.

```
<div id="block1">
   <input type="text" class="class1" value="a">
   <input type="text" class="class2" value="b">
   <input type="checkbox" class="class3"> checkbox
   <select class="class4">
       <option value="0">White</option>
       <option value="1">Brown</option>
       <option value="2">Gray</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

and

```
<div id="block2">
   <input type="text" class="class1" value="a">
   <input type="text" class="class2" value="b">
   <input type="checkbox" class="class3"> checkbox
   <select class="class4">
       <option value="0">White</option>
       <option value="1">Brown</option>
       <option value="2">Gray</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

on one page.

I want both blocks to look absolutely the same way. So, if you change something in the block1, the same thing happened in the block2 and the same changes for block1, if block2 changed respectively.

So, I want

```
$("#block1").change(function () {
    //apply ALL values from block1 to block2
});
$("#block2").change(function () {
    //apply ALL values from block2 to block1
});
```

That includes the values from input texts, input checkboxes and even selected option chosen values. The classes and types of all inputs are the absolutely the same respectively, the number and the value of options in the select boxes are also the same respectively.

What's the shortest way to do that using jQuery? Is it possible to "copy" the values with one jQuery string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a single generic change handler for all elements:

Add a class to main elements:

```
<div id="block1" class="blockClass">
```

JS

```
 /* ":input" selector includes all form controls*/
 $('.blockClass :input').change(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $otherInput = $('.blockClass').not($this.closest('.blockClass')).find('.' + this.className);
    var isCheckable = $this.is(':radio,:checkbox');
    if (isCheckable) {
        $otherInput.prop('checked', this.checked);
    } else {    
        $otherInput.val($this.val());
    }
})
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/5ghRS/

Comment: Why can't I double my vote? You code helps to study jQuery even faster than reading any book. Thank you.

Comment: ahh that's why forums like this are great learning tools...I learn something new every day here

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it is possible to use a single line copy strategy, but only for a single type of input tag. THe problem is that the 'value' of different input tags must be handled different. So either you need a conditional inside the copy strategy (callback or switch), or you need different copy handlers.

I'd go for the later, since you can identify different types of input tags easily using jquery selectors.

Comment: only need different strategy for checkable vs value change..see my solution

Comment: @charlietfl And what about suer defined input tags or special behaviour of tags? But for basic html tags and standard behaviour you are right. Not sure which approach is more elegant though...

Comment: special behavior? Like what? OP just wants form controls to be bound together. Feel free to modify demo for conditions that would make it fail, otherwise is all conjecture

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine. Here the first line just clearing the existing `html` and appending the cloned objects from `#block1`

you must manually fire another line of code the select the value of the dropdown

```
$("#block2").html('').append($("#block1").clone(true))
//$("#block2 select").val($("#block1 select").val())
```

**Updates:**

```
$("#block1 select").each(function(){
       var cls = $(this).attr("class");
       $("#block2").find("select."+cls+"").val($(this).val());
   });
```

**Update:**

Its working fine. see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nRymf/3/)

**Update 2**

Updated `clone()` to `clone(true)` to specify event handlers also should be copied

Comment: Sorry, $("#block2 select").val($("#block1 select").val()) will copy only the first select value.
Also, $("#block2").html('').append($("#block1").clone()) will clone the whole content of the first block, not just input and select values, but the text and everything.

Comment: @Haradzieniec, See the updated code, i added fiddle, its working fine

Comment: Unfortunately, it does NOT.
http://jsfiddle.net/nRymf/2/
If you have more than one select box, it doesn't work. It applies the value from the FIRST select box from block1 to ALL select boxes from block2.

Comment: Thank you for .each() function! That was probably it!

Comment: need to add arguments to include events with `clone()`

Answer (score 1):

The text box values could be generalized by using something like below:

```
$(function() {
            $(".class1").live('keypress', function() {
                $(".class3").val($(this).val());
            });
            $(".class2").live('keypress', function() {
                $(".class4").val($(this).val());
            });

        });
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nRymf/2/) for copying values from first and second

Answer (score 0):

Let's make this dynamic.

For `<input type="text" />` information will be transferred `onkeyup`, means the moment you type in it.

For `<input type="checkbox" />` information will be transferred `onchange`, means the moment the status of this checkbox is changed (either checked or unchecked).

For `<select></select>` information will be transferred `onchange`, means the moment you change the selected value.

```
<div id="block1">
   <input type="text" id="id1" class="class1" value="a" onkeyup="Update()">
   <input type="text" id="id2" class="class2" value="b" onkeyup="Update()">
   <input type="checkbox" id="id3" class="class3" onchange="Update()"> checkbox
   <select class="class4" id="id4" onchange="Update()">
       <option value="0">White</option>
       <option value="1">Brown</option>
       <option value="2">Gray</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Note that it's better to use `ID` rather than `CLASS`.

```
function Update()
{
    var input1 = document.getElementById("id1").value;
    var input2 = document.getElementById("id2").value;
    var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("id3").checked;
    var select1 = document.getElementById("id4").value;
    document.getElementById("id5").value=input1;
    document.getElementById("id6").value=input2;
    document.getElementById("id7").checked=checkbox1;
    document.getElementById("id8").value=select1;
}

<div id="block2">
   <input type="text" id="id5" class="class1" value="a" onkeyup="Update2()">
   <input type="text" id="id6" class="class2" value="b" onkeyup="Update2()">
   <input type="checkbox" id="id7" class="class3" onchange="Update2()"> checkbox
   <select id="id8" class="class4" onchange="Update2()">
       <option value="0">White</option>
       <option value="1">Brown</option>
       <option value="2">Gray</option>
   </select>
</div> 

function Update2()
{
    var input1 = document.getElementById("id5").value;
    var input2 = document.getElementById("id6").value;
    var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("id7").checked;
    var select1 = document.getElementById("id8").value;
    document.getElementById("id1").value=input1;
    document.getElementById("id2").value=input2;
    document.getElementById("id3").checked=checkbox1;
    document.getElementById("id4").value=select1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it could be rewritten using jQuery even without adding any changes into the <div>.

Comment: You write: Note that it's better to use ID rather than CLASS.
Why do you suggest to have the same ids in two different divs on the same page?
Also I believe the proper solution with jQuery takes no more than 4 strings.

Comment: I didn't, look at my solution: id1 -> id8

Comment: Please read my question carefully. Your answer could be fine for another question. Thank you.